# How to retrieve data from Kinect using rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, turtlebot, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community

I am trying to retrieve image and point cloud data from kinect, which is connected to the ASUS 1025C netbook. The green LED on kinect is blinking, which I am assuming confirms that it is getting power from turtlebot 2 Kobuki base.

All sensors are reported okay on Kobuki dashboard.

At step 3.1.3 (3D Visualization) of turtlebot bringup groovy instructions for installing and setting up turtlebot2 and workstation, when I run

```
> roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch
> roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

the display GUI comes up, where turtlebot's position with respect to grid map updates as I manually move turtlebot's base. Laser or Image on the other hand, do not provide any information on this GUI. Selecting **Image** from the display list brings up the Image window with **No Image** written in it.

What are other checks that can be performed to make sure the kinect "service" (not sure what ROS term for this would be) is running and to see if the connection is okay?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87631/how-to-retrieve-data-from-kinect-using-rviz/) by [ibot](https://answers.ros.org/users/7476/ibot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To see if the Kinect is publishing RGB images, use:

> rostopic echo /camera/rgb/image_color

Since rviz isn't displaying the image though, this will most likely fail too. You can also try:

> rosnode list

and check for the "openni_camera" node.

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0